# Angularjs custom directive error

Tags: angularjs-directive

Can anyone please help what is wrong here in this directive...

```
app.directive('colorList', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<button ng-click ='showHideColors()' type='button'>"
            + "{{isHidden?'Show Available colors':'Hide Available colors'}}"
            + "</button> <div ng-hide='isHidden' id='colorContainer'>"
            + "</div>",
        link: function ($scope, $element) {

            $scope.isHidden = true;
            $scope.showHideColors() = function () {
                $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
            }

            var colorContainer = $element.find('div');
            angular.forEach($scope.colorsArray, function (color) {
                var appendString = "<div style = 'background-color:" + color + "'>" + color + "</div>";
                colorContainer.append(appendString);
            });

        }
    };


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot one issue with the following code

```
$scope.showHideColors() = function () { $scope.isHidden = ! scope.isHidden; }
```

You have added () after the function name. So just remove it like below:

```
$scope.showHideColors = function () { $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden; }
```